# How to know which version of oculus integration in installed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

In a Unity project, how can I check which version of Oculus Integration in installed ?

Answer (score 3):

- Open Assets/Oculus/VR/Scripts/OVRPlugin.cs
- Scroll to the last private static class OVRP_* in file, take note of the version number
- Search the OVRPlugin version mentioned here in the release notes:

  https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/unity-integration

Example:

private static class OVRP_1_71_0

--> OVRPlugin version  1.71

Version 39.0 has this version of OVRPlugin.

To help, here is a table of some recent versions. For other numbers, check the link above.

| OVRPlugin | Oculus Integration |
| --- | --- |
| 1.75 | 43.0 |
| 1.74 | 42.0 |
| 1.73 | 41.0 |
| 1.72 | 40.0 |
| 1.71 | 39.0 |
| 1.70 | 38.0 |
| 1.69 | 37.0 |

Answer (score 0):

Another way: click on Oculus/Voice SDK/About and check the Voice SDK version.

Comment: That would be great, but unfortunately it is not reliable. 
The voice SDK version does not always match the integration SDK. For example, in Oculus integration  47.0 - Release Notes  we can find:

The SDK **v47.0** comes bundled with the OVRPlugin 1.78 and the following integrations: Voice **46.0**, Platform 47.0, Interaction 47.0, Audio Spatializer 47.0, and LipSync 29.0.